# Как установить задержку у ObjectAnimator

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Есть вот такая анимация:

```
ObjectAnimator progress = new ObjectAnimator().ofFloat(progressBar,"progress",0,mTotalCount);
progress.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(0.7f));
```

При написании аннимации в `.xml`  - есть такой параметр как `offset`, который я как понимаю мог сделать задержку анимации. Меня интересует как можно сделать подобную задержку используя `ObjectAnimator`

Comment: offset - это не задержка, а "смещение" - с какой позиции будет начата анимация

Comment: просто указывалось значение в миллисекундах я и подумал что задержка, вообщем как можно подобного эффекта достичь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
ObjectAnimator progress = new ObjectAnimator().ofFloat(progressBar,"progress",0,mTotalCount);
progress.setStartDelay(1000);
progress.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(0.7f));
```

Comment: да, то что нужно!